# How can I fetch two api in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I need to fetch two APIs, one has all username and country and another API has user info. So I fetch the first API:

```js
let getUsername = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  fetch(userUrl).then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.map((x => x.name))
  }).then(function(response) {
    var name = response
    console.log(name)
    return name
  })
})
```

and it the return value should be like that

```
[{name:'carlos',country:'mexico'},{name:'jenny',country:'germany'}]
```

and that array is only exist in getUsername fuction but I need to use that to fetch another api

```js
names = []
let promisesArray = names.map(name => {
  // make a new promise for each element of cities
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let url = `http:// userinfo/${name}`
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      var data = JSON.parse(body)
      var results = data.main
      // resolve once we have some data
      resolve(results);
    });
  })
})

Promise.all(promisesArray)
  .then(function(results) {
    console.log(results)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

What I need is I need to make a user array that only has a name from first API, so I can use map function to fetch second API.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? What you've posted  isn't syntactically valid; give a [mcve].

Comment: If you get all object why will you do extra steps to remove extra data, if you just need the name...? use the name inside map to fetch the other api

Comment: what I tried to do is first get api data from user personal info. and the personal info has name and country. and what I only need is names. so for example , var names=[carlos,jenny,Rodrigo] / and second, I need to fetch api by name. `person/data/${name}`. So what I really need to do is first get name from first api and fetch second api by using data from first api. sorry english is not my first language. so I'm really bad at explain

Answer (score 0):

Just destructure `name` out in your `map` call when you define `users`:

```
const users = userarray.map(({ name }) => fetch(`http://api.userdata.${name}`));
```

If you want it to be called `username` too, just alias it:

```
const users = userarray.map(({ name: username }) => fetch(`http://api.userdata.${username}`));
```

Comment: But I dont have userarray. I need to make that userarray from fisrt api fetch. and I don't know how to make a userarray from fetch function.